# Hide and show functionality not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing and show functionality I'm tried scenarios but it is not working, Please let me know what i did mistake.

- My code :

  ```
  function showButtons() {

      $("#view").click(function(){
          $("#allversion").show();
      });
      $("#view").click(function(){
          $("#allversion").hide();
      });
  }

  <div id="allversion" style="display:none">
     SOME DISPLY CODE HERE
  </div>
  ```

let me know the changes i need to made

```
<a onclick="showButtons()" id="view">View More</a>
```

Comment: Use the editor script snippet please.

Comment: [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_toggle) nice example

Comment: Your code should work. Your problem might be that your script is running before the DOM. Either move the script to the bottom of the page or enclose it in a $(document),ready(function(){});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that every time you call function `showButtons` that binds additional 2 click events every time (so clicking on link 2 times you will have 4 events in total). And your code shows *and* hides element at the same time.

You need to toggle it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#view').click(function() {
    $('#allversion').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
#allversion {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="view">View More</a>
<div id="allversion">VISIBLE!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works with me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function showButtons() {


        $("#allversion").toggle();

}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="allversion" >
   SOME DISPLY CODE HERE
</div>

<a onclick="showButtons()" id="view">View More</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use `toggle` method. The problem is that you have to use one single `click` event handler.

```js
$("#view").click(function(e){
    $("#allversion").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="allversion" >
   SOME DISPLY CODE HERE
</div>
<a id="view">View More</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

change to the following code, it should work.

```
<a id="view">View More</a>

var isClicked = false;
$( "#view" ).click(function() {
   if (isClicked == true) {
   $("#allversion").css("display", "none");
   isClicked = false;
   }
   else {
   $("#allversion").css("display", "inline");
   isClicked = true;
   }
});
```

Also you can use .toggle() to switch the visibility.

```
<a id="view">View More</a>

$( "#view" ).click(function() {
   $("#allversion").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call onclick="showButtons()" event for that. You can easily hide and show your section something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#view").click(function(){
        $("#allversion").toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use toggle as suggested by others or you can try this

```
$("#view").click(function(){
if($("#allversion").hasClass('show'))
{
  $("#allversion").removeClass('show').addClass('hide');

}
else
{
  $("#allversion").removeClass('hide').addClass('show');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your question "Why isn't my code working?".

If your code is exactly as is here as on your site, it's not working because the script is initializing before the DOM is loaded.

Move your script to the bottom of the page or put it in to a

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Code goes here
});
```